Number of graph having only vertex of odd degree
I apologize if the question is not well formalized. I have no background on graph theory.
I would like to compute the number of undirected graph having the property that each vertex has an odd degree.
I suspect the problem to be quite well know, but I didn't find any answer online. I tried to get condition on the adjacency matrix of the graph, without sucess.
